# os.path.isdir() under Python os module

Tags: python

I have a question about python sys module,here is the screenshot:

[image]

but actually,the "QPython" is a folder too,so i don't understand why the output is 'False'.thank you for your help!

Comment: where is daima and where is Qpython? How could you be in two different directories at once?

Comment: As per the output, it seems that `QPython` is a directory under `daima` @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @ZdaR, yep, that was more a rhetorical  question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it is inside the `daima` folder see, the output of the `os.getcwd()`. So `os.path.isdir('\\daima\\QPython')` would return `True` instead.

Comment: i tried and it returns True,So when i want to use "os.path.isdir()", should i wirte the  Absolute Path?